# Subtracting sum of previous rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, running-totals

I want to create total field in this table. But in SQL server 2008 can't use 'order by' in OVER clause.

I have same PO and difference INV. I want to Qty field minus Quantity field and next row Total field minus Quantity field.
This is a structure table.

[image]

And this's a result.

[image]

This is my code but it's error at ORDER BY.

```
select t2.BaseRef 'PO',t2.BaseQty 'qty', t1.NumAtCard 'INV',
        t2.Quantity 'Quantity',
        t2.BaseQty - SUM(t2.Quantity) OVER (ORDER BY t1.DocDate) AS 'total'
from OPDN t1 
        INNER JOIN PDN1 t2 ON t1.DocEntry = t2.DocEntry
```

Can I use other way for sort this data?

Comment: Unclear. Create a fiddle, please...

Comment: Row 1 total =  500(Qty) - 100(Quantity)
Row 2 total = 400(Total from Row1) - 200(Quantity)
Row 3 total = 200(Total from Row1) - 200(Quantity)

Comment: We need to look at your table's structures and sample data which must give the result you show.

Comment: I add table structures in questions.

Comment: I do not see `DocDate` field mentioned in OVER clause...

Answer (score 1):

If `SUM() OVER()` is not supported, you may try with the following approach. Rows are ordered by INV number as text (INV100, INV105, ...), not as number (100, 105, ...).

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #PO (
    PO varchar(10),
    DocEntry int,
    Qty int
)
CREATE TABLE #INV (
    INV varchar(10),
    DocEntry int,
    Qty int
)
INSERT INTO #PO (PO, DocEntry, Qty) VALUES ('A123', 1, 500)
INSERT INTO #PO (PO, DocEntry, Qty) VALUES ('B123', 2, 200)
INSERT INTO #INV (INV, DocEntry, Qty) VALUES ('IV100', 1, 100)
INSERT INTO #INV (INV, DocEntry, Qty) VALUES ('IV102', 2, 10)
INSERT INTO #INV (INV, DocEntry, Qty) VALUES ('IV105', 1, 200)
INSERT INTO #INV (INV, DocEntry, Qty) VALUES ('IV106', 2, 190)
INSERT INTO #INV (INV, DocEntry, Qty) VALUES ('IV112', 1, 200)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
    p.PO, 
    p.Qty,
    i.INV,
    i.Qty AS Quantity,
    Total = p.Qty - 
            (
             SELECT SUM(rt.Qty) 
             FROM #INV rt 
             WHERE (rt.DocEntry = i.DocEntry) AND (rt.INV <= i.INV)
            )
FROM #PO p
LEFT JOIN #INV i ON (p.DocEntry = i.DocEntry)
ORDER BY p.DocEntry, i.INV
```

Output:

```
PO      Qty INV     Quantity    Total
A123    500 IV100   100         400
A123    500 IV105   200         200
A123    500 IV112   200         0
B123    200 IV102   10          190
B123    200 IV106   190         0
```

Comment: This approach will break down when Invoice "IV1000" is created, being [incorrectly] sorted between "IV100" and "IV101".  Whilst using a purely numeric, surrogate key to uniquely identify each Invoice would improve the situation, things like Sequences are NOT guaranteed to be sequential (or even "always increasing") but only unique.   You need to find a definitive way of getting these items into the right order; the database will not intrinsically do this for you.

Comment: @PhillW. Of course, sort order is based on text values (as is mentioned in the answer). If the invoice numbers are greater than 999, `ORDER BY p.DocEntry, CONVERT(int, REPLACE(i.INV, 'IV', ''))` is one possible approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PO.PO, 
       PO.Qty, 
       INV.INV, 
       INV.Quantity, 
       PO.Qty - SUM(INV.Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY PO.PO ORDER BY INV.DocDate) total
FROM PO, INV
WHERE PO.DocEntry = INV.DocEntry
ORDER BY PO.PO, INV.DocDate
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7f45a1c4bff379b6b58a6754a151e966)

Comment: In SQL server 2008 can't use ORDER BY in OVER clause. Console display this ("Incorrect syntax near 'order'.")